# SqlCommand using Parameters but still it is creating Multiple Plans for One Query

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, sql-server-2019, parameter

I have the below code, I'm using parameters, but still it is generating many Duplicate SQL Execution Plans. What is wrong and how it can be fixed, please?

```
    string cmdString = @"INSERT INTO tb_RA_GLID (glid_StoreNumber, 
                                          glid_StoreName, 
                                          glid_FirstBusinessDate, 
                                          glid_LastBusinessDate, 
                                          glid_DateCreated, 
                                          glid_TimeCreated, 
                                          glid_ExportVersion, 
                                          glid_GLMappingVersion, 
                                          glid_POSModelOrType, 
                                          glid_POSVersion) 
                                          VALUES (@StoreNumber    , @StoreName    , @FirstBusinessDate    , @LastBusinessDate    , @DateCreated     , @TimeCreated   , @ExportVersion    , @GLMappingVersion    , @POSModelOrType    , @POSVersion     );
                                                 "; //SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
        {
            comm.Connection = conn;
            comm.CommandText = cmdString;
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StoreNumber", columns[1]);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StoreName", columns[2]);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstBusinessDate", DateTime.ParseExact(columns[3], "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastBusinessDate", DateTime.ParseExact(columns[4], "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateCreated", DateTime.ParseExact(columns[5], "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeCreated", DateTime.ParseExact(columns[6], "HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExportVersion", columns[7]);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GLMappingVersion", columns[8]);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POSModelOrType", columns[9]);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POSVersion", columns[10]);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //object returnObj = comm.ExecuteScalar();
                //if (returnObj != null)
                //{
                //    int.TryParse(returnObj.ToString(), out glid);
                //}
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Do not use `AddWithValue` to add parameters to the collection. SqlClient will infer the SqlDbType based on the .NET type and define the parameter length for string types based on the actual value length rather than the maximum length. Each permutation of differing parameters/lengths for the same query results in a different plan and [bloats the cache](https://www.dbdelta.com/dont-bloat-proc-cache-with-parameters/).

Also, an incorrect guess at the SqlDbType can negatively impact performance. For example, a .NET `string` will result in an `nvarchar` parameter type. This will not be sargable with a varchar column and a legacy SQL collation, preventing an index on the column from being used efficiently.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Will try to change them like this example: selectCommand.Parameters.Add(“@LastName”, SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = lastName;       and how it goes.